# Como saber se uma string contém outra?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma `List<string>` com quatro itens:

```
C:\Users\Producao\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteRelatorios\bpa\Content\Upload\LFCES004.txtb9109712-d3f2-4151-bbac-7fbc82ed99de
C:\Users\Producao\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteRelatorios\bpa\Content\Upload\LFCES018.txteeba927c-47c9-41ff-9643-4a0556244b26
C:\Users\Producao\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteRelatorios\bpa\Content\Upload\LFCES021.txt84a0effb-a3a3-4790-a8e4-62d80e23b0ad
C:\Users\Producao\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteRelatorios\bpa\Content\Upload\LFCES037.txta1189537-b589-4161-9ce6-f62b2aecbab9
```

Cada linha dessa é um arquivo `.txt`

Quero saber deles, qual linha tem a palavra `LFCES004`, `LFCES018`, `LFCES021` e `LFCES037`

Ex.: `if (linha1 contém 'LFCES004')`

Comment: Cara só usar  .Contains(valor)

Comment: Não entendi os votos negativos nem o voto para fechar pela pergunta "não estar clara o suficiente". Acho que uma prova de intepretação de texto deveria ser pré-requisito para se poder dar esse tipo de voto de fechamento ¬¬

Comment: Também não entendi @Renan, mas fazer o que né?

Comment: Era bastante óbvio que uma perguntas simples assim já teria várias respondidas, e tem mais ainda.

Comment: é que pesquisei por uma string dentro de outra, não pesquisei por comparação de strings, já que meu pensamento não era esse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra checar se uma `string` está contida na outra, basta usar o [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (linha1.Contains("LFCES004"))
```

Answer (score 4):

A classe `String` possui um método de instância chamado [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) que atende a sua necessidade.

O método recebe uma string, e indica se a string informada é uma substring da instância na qual foi chamado.

i.e.:

```
string foo = "abc", bar = "ab", ni = "ad";

foo.Contains(bar); // o retorno será true
foo.Contains(ni); // o retorno será false
```

Note que uma string sempre é substring dela mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Basta usares `Contains`

```
var Value1 = "ddabcgghh";

if (Value1.Contains("abc"))
{
    [..]
}
```

Para verificares com uma Lista tenta o seguinte:

```
foreach(string item in minhaLista)
{
  if(item.Contains("ABCABC"))
       return item;
}
```